# Dependency declaration error in ANTLR 4.10.1

Tags: gradle, dependencies, version, antlr4, conflict

It seems there is a conflict of version for the antlr-runtime lib pulled by ANTLR 4.10.1: 3.5.2 versus 3.5.3.
Here is the gradle analyze result:
[image: gradle dependency check]

Antlr team can you confirm please?

Comment: https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/853c887958be301f0338d5c66bb20449fdaa10d2/pom.xml#L50 https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/ee62e23da9669c20509984e0013664a851565e8f/tool/pom.xml#L32 Please create an issue in the ST and/or Antlr4 github repositories so the issue is tracked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been raised on project's github:
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/3733

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this issue attempting to use ANTLR4 in a PHP environment.
While the issue still exists afaik (I'm on PHP7.4.3 and upgrading to PHP8 is not an option for me so it may work fine on later versions of PHP).

My workaround went as follows:

- generated the php code using antlr as instructed here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr-php-runtime
- discovered errors where the runtime version does not match the generated code
- went to github and found the following codechanges: https://github.com/antlr/antlr-php-runtime/pull/23/files
- made these changes by hand in the runtime files in vendor/antlr/antlr4-php-runtime/src/

This got my code communicating the same ATN type between classes (the first of the differences between the runtime version and my generated classes). But walking my grammar gave me another error - probably another difference between runtime and generated versions.

The code for this one was in the antlr/antlr4 repo instead of the antlr-php-runtime repo:

- I found issue "PHP target runtime crashes with "Undefined offset: 0 in ATNDeserializer.php on line 731" #3509
  (https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/3509)
- In the posts, the last commenter (kaby76) includes a zipfile called "Generated.zip" that contains the generated source code as it is supposed to look like.
- I downloaded and extracted the files here. My error was occurring in ATNDeserializer.php and I found that the sourcecode from Kaby's zipfile did not include the ATN fixes I described above but it did contain the addition of IsFeatureSupported.
- Since my grammar does not produce the indicated ADDED_UNICODE_SMP, I just commented that portion out in the deserialize function:

  `...
  // First, deserialize sets with 16-bit arguments <= U+FFFF.
  $this->readSets($sets, function () {
  return $this->readInt();
  });`

  // Next, if the ATN was serialized with the Unicode SMP feature,
  // deserialize sets with 32-bit arguments <= U+10FFFF.
  /*
  if ($this->isFeatureSupported(self::ADDED_UNICODE_SMP, $this->uuid)) {
  $this->readSets($sets, function () {
  return $this->readInt32();
  });
  }
  */
  $this->readEdges($atn, $sets);
  ...

Although this got me working, it is a workaround and not recommended as a long-term solution.